# How to use Linq with Reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

To get the name from id using reflection from an enumerable. I'm using:

```
foreach(string idValue in Values)
{
    var listSource = itemsSource as IEnumerable;
    Type listType = listSource.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0]
    PropertyInfo idProperty = listType.GetType().GetProperty("Id");
    PropertyInfo nameProperty = listType.GetType().GetProperty("Name");

    foreach (var listItem in listSource)
    {
        if (idValue.Equals(idProperty.GetValue(listItem, null).ToString()))
        {
            value = nameProperty.GetValue(listItem, null).ToString();
            break;
        }
    }
    //do something with value.
}
```

How to use Linq with reflection, so that I need not loop through elements for each value of 'idValue' in the outer loop??

something like:

`reflectionList.Select(x=> x.idProperty == idValue)` and use it to get value of `nameProperty`

Please help.

Comment: Using LINQ doesn't avoid loops, it just means you don't need to write them out.

Comment: Add a using to System.Linq?

Comment: What is your question? _"How to convert this to Linq"_?

Comment: @Servy I had assumed OP meant when saying 'so that I need not loop though elements..' that they meant using the foreach sytnax.

Comment: @Jeevan: not sure what *value* brings to you having a LINQ here. Most likely it would make code more messier and harder to undertsand.

Comment: @Botonomous you would be surprised about the number of people who think that Linq is faster because through some sort of magic it wouldn't have to iterate over all items.

Comment: I'm confused - if you know the property names why are you using reflection?

Comment: And how can you reference `listItem` outside of the inner loop?

Comment: @DStanley because they are assigning to a value which is scoped somewhere else.

Comment: @Botonomous: I believe the problem is that `listItem` is used outside of the loop that then declares `var listItem in listSource`. One would expect the compiler to complain either that the use outside of the loop was undeclared or that the loop is redeclaring a variable.

Comment: Well your code does not compile as-is without other context so it's difficult to understand exactly why you're using reflection, what you're trying to do and what you're having problems with. Are you looking for items in `listSource` that have `Id` values within `Values`?

Comment: @Botonomous My question is why can't the OP just do `value = listItem.Name`

Comment: @DStanley Probably because `listItem` is hidden with type `object`, so `listItem.Name` wouldn't compile

Comment: @DStanley
itemsSource comes as an IEnumerable
I don't know what Type it is.
I know property names by string values. I cannot say listItem."Id" to get the property value.
My mistake, wrong code.. updated code to use Type.

Comment: @CodeCaster
I agree. I'm one of those people who thinks Linq is faster than a loop. Seems like I'm wrong. Thank you for clearing that up for me.

Comment: @Jeevan So you don't know the type but you know it has `Id` and `Name` properties?  Do you know what the underlying type _should_ be?  If so you could use `Cast<T>` on the `IEnumerable` to turn it into an `IEnumerable<T>` and then use regular Linq projections from there.  Or could it be different, unrelated types, each with those properties?

Comment: @DStanley yes. i know the property names but not the type. during runtime type is known using     listSource.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0]

Answer (score 0):

This couldn't be tested, since I don't really know what types you're using (for `Values` specifically), nor what the expected result is.

```
value = listSource.Where(item => idValue.Equals(idProperty.GetValue(item, null).ToString()))
    .Select(item => nameProperty.GetValue(item, null).ToString())
    .First();
```

We first get all the items corresponding to your `if` condition, then translate them to a simple string by `nameProperty`, then retrieve only the first (which should also be the only) string item.

Comment: Thank you for your response. problem is I'm not able to use .Where or Linq even after using System.Linq. That's may be because IEnumerable type is not known at the point.

Comment: You clearly use `IEnumerable` in your own code, so that can't be the issue. What is the error you get?